# Where are the css(s) in drupal 7?

Tags: css, drupal, directory

I'm new to drupal and i was trying to do several common css tasks, like changing color background, links color etc. I guess i have not understood where the drupal css are. I tried to modify style.css in the folder my-site-name/sites/all/themes/mythemename/, which seems to be the main css, but it seems to have no effect on the site, even using the directive "!important".

So, where's the drupal 7 main css?

Comment: Try to clear your site cache in Admin > Configuration > Development > Performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "Main CSS". Drupal core uses some CSS files. Each module its own CSS. Then each theme overrides CSS using its own css files. You can have as much css files as you like in your theme and with any acceptable name.

Probably you have to **[clear the caches](https://drupal.org/node/42055)** to see the results. If not, check the css styles with Firebug to see what is happening. This way, also, you can see what css files apply styles for each page/element.

Comment: Thank you! Checking with firebug i could get the right css, which was exactly the one i was modifying. I could verify it modifying the attributes of link, but still no luck with the background, which seems to be a bit more difficult to identify and change. Probably i'm working on a wrong div and this made me think i was modifying the wrong div...